# Choropleth map with GeoPandas and Folium error

Tags: shapefile, json, choropleth, geopandas, folium

I am trying to generate a leaflet Choropleth map as in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/folium.

I am importing a shapefile as a geoDataframe which later on I am converting to a json file that I can input in the folium choropleth function. I am passing the geoframe.geometry field to the geo_path input and a specific geoframe.data to color out the different polygon coming as geometry.

I get this error:

```
  'File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\folium\folium.py", line 606, in choropleth
    geo_data = open(geo_path)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-8719814.090035686,'
```

My code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import shapely as sh
import numpy as np
import random
import folium



lotes = gpd.read_file("shapefiles/reProj/Lotes_Datos_epsg3857_SM.shp")
lotes.crs = {'init' : 'epsg:3857'}

geoPath = lotes.geometry.to_json()
data1 = lotes.Area_Total.to_json()

mapa = folium.Map([0, -78], zoom_start=3, tiles='Stamen Toner',API_key='wrobstory.map-12345678')

mapa.choropleth(geo_path=geoPath, data=data1, 
    columns=['Lote', 'data1'], 
    key_on='feature.id',
    fill_color='YlGn', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='data1')
mapa

mapa.save(outfile = 'shapefiles/reProj/test.html')
```

My coding level is beginner.

Any ideas?

shapefile: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztvcr0qar4870ht/Lotes_Datos_epsg3857_SM.shp?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

The first issue (There may be others) is that geo_path expects a file, you want geo_str, which just expects a string.

```
mapa.choropleth(geo_str=geoPath, data=data1, 
                columns=['Lote', 'data1'], 
                key_on='feature.id',
                fill_color='YlGn', 
                fill_opacity=0.7, line_opacity=0.2,
                legend_name='data1')
```

Answer (score 1):

GeoPandas are currently not supported as input in the `chloropleth()` method. You should try to use `folium.GeoJson(lotes).add_to(mapa)`, as specified in the [Geopandas Python Notebook](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/Geopandas.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for Rmatt's answer:

```
One = gpd.read_file('1.shp')  
mapa = folium.Map([2, -75], zoom_start=10, tiles='Stamen Toner',API_key='*******')
folium.GeoJson(One).add_to(mapa)
mapa
```